# R - Manhattan / Euclidean distance calculations into a matrix

Tags: r

I would like to ask help on distance measures for continuous variables

There is an example:

```
x1 = (0,0)
x2 = (1,0)
x3 = (5,5)
```

The example is to find the distance matrix for L1-norm and L2-norm(Euclidean).
I don't know how to compute in R to get the following answer:

[image]

I have tried to do it like this but it didn't work as expected.

```
y2 <- c(0,0)
y3 <- c(1,0)
y4 <- c(5,5)
y5 <- rbind(y2,y3,y4)
dist(y5)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
y2 <- c(0,0)
y3 <- c(1,0)
y4 <- c(5,5)

mat <- rbind(y2, y3, y4)

d1 <- dist(mat, upper=TRUE, diag=TRUE, method="manhattan")
d1
#    y2 y3 y4
# y2  0  1 10
# y3  1  0  9
# y4 10  9  0

d2 <- dist(mat, upper=TRUE, diag=TRUE)^2
d2
#    y2 y3 y4
# y2  0  1 50
# y3  1  0 41
# y4 50 41  0
```

Comment: Nice answer. May I suggest that you write True instead of just T in the dist function parameters? It makes it easier for someone not familiar with the function to understand.

Comment: I have now looked at bit at some r-code made by others (I have used r myself previously). It seems that using T/F is widely accepted. It is probably just me, coming from a programming background, that do not like r-abbreviations. Sorry if I have caused some confusion regarding coding style in r.

Comment: @Stefan It's okay in either way.

Comment: @BonBonCheng Please accept my answer by check the tick on the left of my answer. Thx!